# "I regret that Mary said that John had bought {something / anything} in that shop"

Tags: some-vs-any

In the following sentences, would you, native English speakers, use the "any" form or the "some" form?

Thank you very much!

a) I regret that Mary said that John had bought {something / anything} in that shop.

b) I regret that it happened that everyone bought {something / anything} in those terrible shops.
        [please imagine that "everyone" refers to a group of tourists]

c) He regrets that Mary believed that John had invited {someone / anyone} to her party.

d) He regrets that Mary knew that {someone / anyone} was saying bad things about her.

e) She regrets that {someone / anyone} has read this book.

(This last one is a little bit different in its structure.)

Comment: I could see "anyone" working  with either one.  Otherwise, I'd choose "something" for all the others.

Comment: Sorry, I think I do not fully understand your answer. Do you mean that with one of the five sentences you would use the "any-" form or the "some-" one and that with the other four you would only use the "some-" form? Thank you!

Comment: Hello, Robert. Where are these example sentences from? It's hard to comment on idiomaticity when the _rest_ of a sentence sounds odd. / Also, in the first example for instance, 'something' would be the normal ('unmarked') choice, but an emphasised 'anything' (and I can think of _two_ situations where it could be) is also a legitimate choice to convey different messages.

Comment: Hello, Edwin. These examples were built by me with the intention to test if it was possible to have an "any" element in an embedded clause under an embedded clause (this is why they sound considerably artificial). I believe that "John regrets that he said anything" is grammatical, but would it still be if there was another level of embedding in between? This is what I try to test with these examples. In any case, thank you for you answer; would you say that, in general, the first four original examples would basically be with "some-", even if, with emphasis, they could be w/ "any-"? Thank you.

Comment: I'll just go with one. a) I regret that Mary said that John had bought something in that shop. No problem grammatically, and I'd say the preferred unmarked choice.

Answer (score 0):

@EdwinAshworth raised a good point, asking where these sentences came from ("It's hard to comment on idiomaticity when the *rest* of a sentence sounds odd").  After reading that, and looking at your sentences again, they do start to look a bit odd.

They appear contrived.  There are too many levels.  I don't think you even need that many levels, if your purpose is to construct sentences that allow you to practice choosing between *something* and *anything*.

I will rewrite your sentences to make them more plausible, and indicate which is better (*something/anything*).  If a different formulation would be better, I'll use that instead.

> a) I wish Mary hadn't told you that **John bought something** in that shop.

> OR

> I wish Mary had told you that **John didn't buy anything** in that shop.

> b) **I don't think anyone** on the tour bus would have **bought anything** from that overpriced shop if the bus hadn't stopped for lunch at the bagel place next door.

> c) I'm sorry you understood John to have **invited some undergrads** to your party. That was a misunderstanding. Actually, they were gate crashers.  It's true that John knows them from his soccer league, but he didn't invite them and he didn't even tell them about your party.  He's planning to ask them tomorrow how they found out about it.

> d) I'm sorry to hear that you've heard the rumor that **someone** is going around slandering you.

> e) The commissioner of education held a press conference to defend the presence of this book on the state's suggested reading list for 11th grade.  In a prepared statement, she expressed profound regret that some school districts have banned it.  She added, "It is a shame that in this day and age, ***any* school** would ban ***any* book**."  But she emphasized that the book is not a required part of the curriculum.  She said that teachers and principals are free to develop their own curriculum.

Comment: Thank you. It may well be that the original sentences were contrived, but I have to say that it was important for me that the word with "any"/"some" was in an embedded clause inside an embedded clause. I think that "John regrets that he said anything" is grammatical; but, would it be if there was another level of embedding in between? This is what the original examples are about. But, again, thank you.

Comment: @RobertTrujillo - Well, I tried to give you some examples with some embedding.  Did they help at all? // Basically, as Edwin said, most of your original examples would normally use "something," but in principle "anything" *could* be used for emphasis.

Comment: Yes, that's true, and your examples are very interesting to me, since they have a lot of context and they indeed sound much more natural. Thank you very much!

Comment: @RobertTrujillo - Whew.  Glad I found a way to help.

Comment: Specific feedback from the downvoter would be appreciated.

Comment: @RobertTrujillo - I added a double-embedded example with "anything." // Note that "regret" is very formal -- I had to introduce a press conference to be able to use it.  More natural is "to be sorry."

Comment: Hello, aparente001. I want to make clear that the downvoter was not me (in fact, I am so new in this page that I am not sure how the voting works; I think I have upvoted you). / Thank you for the example you added and for the clarification about register.

Comment: @RobertTrujillo - I knew it wasn't you!  Because earlier I was wondering about that combination of positive comment but zero votes in either direction, and I checked what the minimum reputation is for upvoting -- turns out you are quite close but not quite there yet. // Glad to help. // If you haven't visited English Language Learners yet, take a look.  You seem to be a quite advanced learner of English.  Nevertheless you may find some interesting things there.

Answer (score 0):

I have chosen two of your sentences to explain:

I regret that Mary said that John had bought something in that shop.  Mary said he bought something and you regret that. It sounds to me like John wasn't supposed to buy anything and Mary has told on him. John regrets he bought anything, meaning he should'd have bought anything at all.

She regrets that {someone / anyone} has read this book.

She regrets someone has read this book means that a specific person has read it and she regrets it. Who is "someone"?

She regrets anyone has read this book means the book was not meant to be read by anyone, it is private.

Answer (score 0):

You “regret” your own actions, not what someone else does. In most of your examples the person saying “I regret” hasn’t actually done something to regret. Only in number 4 it *may* be the speakers fault.

For example, “I regret that Mary said” doesn’t make sense. “Mary regrets that she said” or “Mary will regret one day that she said… “ make sense.

Comment: I regret that Mary said x is fine. You can regret the actions of others.

Answer (score -1):

Any- form mainly used in negative sentences, All of the sentences above are in any- form.

Comment: Max, I appreciate your good-hearted willingness to help others.  However, I want to warn you that many of the participants at ELU are quite rigorous when evaluating an answer.  One has to include at least one reference to a reputable source.  Otherwise, if you just want to help someone informally, it is better to write a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I want to write a comment, but I need at least 50 reputations to write a comment and I do not have.

Comment: You can build up your reputation to 50 with a bit of patience.

Comment: Thank you Max and aparente001. Regarding the answer by Max, I have to say that, in fact, there is no explicit negation in the original examples in my question. This is why it is interesting that, at least in some similar cases (like "John regrets that he said anything"), a word with "any-" can be used. However, it is my impression (and the other answers tend to coincide) that, with an extra level of embedding, the elements with "any-" are clearly worse. Thank you, in any case.